# Can someone please explain this bit of Python code?

Tags: python, closures

I started working in Python just recently and haven't fully learned all the nuts and bolts of it, but recently I came across [this post](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/67666) that explains why python has closures, in there, there is a sample code that goes like this:

```
y = 0

def foo():
    x = [0]
    def bar():
        print x[0], y
    def change(z):
        global y
        x[0] = y = z

    change(1)
    bar()
    change(2)
    bar()
    change(3)
    bar()
    change(4)
    bar()

foo()

1 1
2 2
3 3
```

and basically I don't understand how it actually works, and what construct like x[0] does in this case, or actually I understand what it's doing, I just don't get how is it this :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before the `nonlocal` keyword was added in Python 3 (and still today, if you're stuck on `2.*` for whatever reason), a nested function just couldn't rebind a local barename of its outer function -- because, normally, an assignment statement to a barename, such as `x = 23`, means that `x` is a local name for the function containing that statement.  `global` exists (and has existed for a long time) to allow assignments to bind or rebind *module-level* barenames -- but nothing (except for `nonlocal` in Python 3, as I said) to allow assignments to bind or rebind names in the outer function.

The solution is of course very simple: since you cannot bind or rebind such a barename, use instead a name that is **not** bare -- an indexing or an attribute of some object named in the outer function.  Of course, said object must be of a type that lets you rebind an indexing (e.g., a list), or one that lets you bind or rebind an attribute (e.g., a function), and a list is normally the simplest and most direct approach for this.  `x` is exactly that list in this code sample -- it exists only in order to let nested function `change` rebind `x[0]`.

Answer (score 5):

It might be simpler to understand if you look at this simplified code where I have removed the global variable:

```
def foo():
    x = [0]
    def bar():
        print x[0]
    def change(z):
        x[0] =  z

    change(1)
    bar()

foo()
```

The first line in foo creates a list with one element. Then `bar` is defined to be a function which prints the first element in `x` and the function `change` modifies the first element of the list. When `change(1)` is called the value of x becomes `[1]`.

Comment: ok, makes sense. but why then if we would've defined x as an integer, say x = 0, then it's value wouldn't change inside the change() function? like they have it in the second block of code in that post?

Comment: @Alex N.: That's actually explained in the article, and also Alex Martelli has also covered it in his post too.

Answer (score 4):

This code is trying to explain when python creates a new variable, and when python reuses an existing variable.  I rewrote the above code slightly to make the point more clear.

```
y = "lion"
def foo():
    x = ["tiger"]
    w = "bear"
    def bar():
        print y, x[0], w
    def change(z):
        global y
        x[0] = z
        y = z
        w = z
    bar()
    change("zap")
    bar()
foo()
```

This will produce this output:

```
lion tiger bear
zap zap bear
```

The point is that the inner function **change** is able to affect the variable **y**, and the elements of array **x**, but it does not change **w** (because it gets its own local variable **w** that is not shared).

Answer (score 2):

x = [0] creates a new list with the value 0 in it. x[0] references the zero-eth element in the list, which also happens to be zero.

The example is referencing closures, or passable blocks of code within code.